# ¿Devolver imagen en formato array de bytes desde URL en internet?

Tags: php

Digamos que tengo esta URL para la imagen:

> https://www.nissan-cdn.net/content/dam/Nissan/global/vehicles/gt-r/r35/eulhd/2_minor_change/overview/17TDIeulhd_GTRHelios026.jpg.ximg.l_full_m.smart.jpg

¿Cómo puedo obtener un array de bytes de esta imagen?

Edito para añadir información sobre lo que he probado pero no me acaba de funcionar:

He hecho esto:

```
$filename = 'https://www.nissan-cdn.net/content/dam/Nissan/global/vehicles/gt-r/r35/eulhd/2_minor_change/overview/17TDIeulhd_GTRHelios026.jpg.ximg.l_full_m.smart.jpg';
$url = preg_replace("/ /", "%20", $filename);
$file = fopen($url, "rb");
$contents = fread($file, filesize($url));
fclose($file);
```

Y me sale el siguiente error:

> Warning: filesize(): stat failed for direccion de la imagen

Comment: a que te refieres con un "array de bytes"? Si te refieres a obtener el archivo como una cadena de caracteres, puedes abrir el enlace y convertirlo con base64. Eso te devolvera una cadena...

Comment: Necesito  hacer algo como esto : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687270/convert-image-to-byte-with-php Pero me da el siguiente error:

failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request: request protocol version denied

Comment: acabo de editar la pregunta con los errores que me salen

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/724391/579895

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que puedes usar file_get_contents para eso:

```
$filename = 'https://www.nissan-cdn.net/content/dam/Nissan/global/vehicles/gt-r/r35/eulhd/2_minor_change/overview/17TDIeulhd_GTRHelios026.jpg.ximg.l_full_m.smart.jpg';

$cadena = file_get_contents(urlencode($filename));
```

Pero pasando el filename por urlencode, para ajustar casos de espacios en blanco y demas.

si necesitas la cadena legible, puedes pasarlo por base64_encode:

```
$result = base64_encode($cadena);
```

Pero ten en cuenta que habra casos que no te permitan leer el archivo directamente, por temas de CORS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). En este caso parece que no tendras problema, pero cuidado con ello.

Comment: Esto es lo que devuelve: https://pastebin.com/R1T9dM9n  es normal?

Comment: te devuelve el contenido del archivo. Al ser una imagen es un archivo binario. Si lo que necesitas es algo con caracteres legibles, pasa $cadena por base64_encode. Te lo edito en la solucion